# Jquery/javascript problem in chrome

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, google-chrome

im trying to do some processing on close event of jquery multiselect plugin [by erichynds](http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/#enabledisable)

the problem is chrome seems to get lost in the following loop,

```
   for(var a in f)
   {    
    var h = f[a];
    $('#modelselect0 optgroup[label='+h+']').each(function(e){         
     var opt = $(this).find('option').filter(':selected');  
     if(opt.length !=0)
     {      
     opt.each(function(){     
      var tempIndex = tt.indexOf(h);       
      if(ff.length!=0)
      {
       ff += ","+$(this).text();
      }
      else
      {
       ff=$(this).text();
      }      
      });     
     }
     else
     {     
      if(ff.length!=0)
      {
       ff += ","+h;
      }
      else
      {
       ff=h;
      }     
     }     
   });    
   }
```

works fine in FF, opera.

any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you perhaps try to write a more specific question title?

Answer (score 1):

try changing:

```
for(var a in f)
```

to:

```
var a;
for(a in f)
```